# Drawing shapes to use as controls

Tags: sharpdevelop

Is there in Sharpdevelop a feature to draw shapes like an ellipses into a form?
In this [Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ellipse), it says that you should drag an ellipse to the form using the toolbox. But I don't see any tools for drawing shapes onto windows forms. Maybe this is just possible with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither SharpDevelop nor Visual Studio have an Ellipse control for Windows Forms in the Toolbox.

The tutorial is for WPF and Visual Studio does have an Ellipse control for WPF but SharpDevelop does not have one that you can drag from the Toolbox. In SharpDevelop you would have to write the XAML yourself to see the Ellipse.